# A question about Gysin exact sequence for cohomology of the orbit space

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

There is a claim in the following thesis regarding the exact sequence of Gysin. Shouldn't the spherical bundle $\mathbb{S}^1 \rightarrow X \rightarrow X/\mathbb{S}^1$ be orientable for the Gysin exact sequence?

I read in some sources that the spherical bundle $\mathbb{S}^1 \rightarrow X \rightarrow X/\mathbb{S}^1$ is orientable for free action of $\mathbb{S}^1$ on $X$, but I could not find a complete reference.

Under what conditions, $\mathbb{S}^1 \rightarrow X \rightarrow X/\mathbb{S}^1$ is orientable fiber bundle. Is it enough to be almost free?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

See Bredon’s *Sheaf Theory* Chapter IV the intro to Section 13. The orbit map of a circle action is always orientable.

Comment: If the orbit map of a circle action is always orientable, then why does the action need to be almost free?

Comment: The statement of the Lemma says why that hypothesis  is being imposed — the isotropy groups are all finite.

Comment: I did'nt understand your comment. As far as I can see, this hypothesis is not used in the proof. I thought this hypothesis was necessary for the Gysin exact sequence.  I thought this was related to the orientability of the spherical fiber bundle.